# How to avoid "Windows protected your PC" warning on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, digital-signature, digital-certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass the smart screen on Win8 when install a signed application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application)

When I download my executable file from my web site (packed in a ZIP file) and then try to run it in Windows 8 the OS shows the following overlay:

[image]

Note that my exe file is **signed with a digital certificate** that is in good standing.

So my question is, what shall I do to avoid this message from being shown to an end-user because the way Microsoft worded and presented it, my software looks like a virus?

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if it makes a difference, I'm using a [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com) digital certificate. It is about 2 and a half months old.

Comment: Read more info. This has happened to me before (well with another antivirus but w/e). Heuristics detect that it's malicious for some reason. Post more info.

Comment: I don't know what else to post. The only thing I noticed is that if I go to the exe file's properties the General tab at the bottom has this message: `This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer`. There's also Unblock button next to it. If I click Unblock, the message in my first post doesn't show.

Comment: No, in the message, below at risk, it says more info. Could you click it please?

Comment: Might be of use: [How to pass the smart screen on Win8 when install a signed application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application)

Comment: @ofstream: Oh, sorry, if I click "More info" it unfurls into Publisher: Giving the name on digital certificate, and App: Name of the exe file. And that is it.

Comment: @adrianbanks: Thanks for the link. And, wow, this is lame: `Reputation is generated and assigned to digital certificates as well as specific files.` So this means that if my certificate is new all users will see is that message. And if they see that message how the f&^# will they open it to build reputation? MS needs to think before they do something like that!

Comment: @AlastairPitts: Yes it's a duplicate, but that other thread doesn't have a definitive answer to the question.

Comment: @user843732 fair enough, but as it's exactly the same question, you should expect that this one will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39437773