# Avoiding SmartScreen warning

Tags: smartscreen

SmartScreen on Windows displays a warning when I open on some of the binaries that I release but not all of them. Do I need to sign all the installers? Is there a cheap way to do that? Recommendations on which certificate issuer to use would be highly appreciated if that is the way to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 SmartScreen with Code Signing .exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839577/windows-10-smartscreen-with-code-signing-exe-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can not sign an application to bypass smart-screen. Smart-screen gives every exe file it comes across a "reputation". The more people open an exe file and trust it, the better its reputation becomes. There is no way to bypass it.