# Generally how many days it takes by Windows smart screen to white list a published digitally signed exe?

Tags: windows, code-signing, whitelist, windows-defender, smartscreen

I have developed a Windows executable which has to be downloaded from my website by a user to run. The exe is code signed by regular certificate(not ev).

My concern is when a user is downloading the software and run, the Windows smart screen is shows warning - *Windows Defender Smart Screen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk. Smart screen displays publisher correctly.* 
I came to know smart screen evaluate an executable in time watching global uses and reports by antivirus or users.

Some of my users machines are configured by admin to block suspicious software and so, there smart screen doesn't show run option like below.

[image]

How much time generally, it should take to white list my software or is there anything I can do as an instant solution?

Comment: It is a secret, safe to assume it will take a lot longer than you hope for.  You can throw more money at it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39437773/1070129