# How to preserve reputation with the SmartScreen Filter in Windows 10 after previous code-signing certificate renewal?

Tags: windows-10, code-signing-certificate, smartscreen

I had a code-signing certificate for the last 3 years. When I signed my software with it, the signature did not cause any `SmartScreen` warnings when the software was downloaded from the Internet.

This certificate was expiring this month, so I renewed it with the same company for another 3 years.

The issue it created is that now when I sign my software, the new certificate does not have any reputation with the Windows 10 `SmartScreen`, so when the software is downloaded and run, it shows this warning:

[image]

*(I've been signing my software with it for over 2 weeks now. And the warning is still there.)*

I know it's a slim chance, but is there a way to link this new certificate to the old one to preserve the old cert's reputation with `SmartScreen`?

PS. This "cert renewal business" and the *loss of reputation* is costing me dearly in the number of installs of my software. Also, why do developers have to pay with the reputation loss for the cert renewals.

Comment: A quick follow-up. I remember I ended up [submitting my executable here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission) to MSFT. I'm not sure if it helped, or not. But it took about 2-3 weeks before my updated signature began being recognized by them again without triggering that nasty warning.

Answer (score 3):

Not an exact answer to your question, but I think this method might help you as well:

Create a small installer package that does nothing else than download and run the real, up to date installer EXE/MSI from a webserver (let's call it "secondary installer") and runs it.

You can update the "secondary installer" as often as you want, but by all means avoid any changes (rebuilds) of the "primary installer".

Why does this work?

- You need to code sign the primary installer only once. As long as the EXE remains as-is, it's signature **and reputation** is valid even when the certificate itself expires (an expired certificate won't let you sign new code, but already signed code remains valid).
- Smart Screen only checks your primary installer. It apparently does not care if that program downloads and runs other programs.

Of course, your primary installer (or, more exactly, it's certificate) still needs to gain reputation, but after that, you're set.

I used [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) along with the [Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/) to create such a "primary installer" (resulting in a ~700 kb Setup).

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting approach. I'd call it a `bypass` of their SmartScreen. I've seen this done many times. Heck, even MS VS installer does a similar thing. So I guess when you download your 2nd executable yourself you obviously clear it's `Mark-of-the-web` stream before running, right. It's a much more involved solution for my liking, but I can see how it may be appropriate. In my case it took about 2-3 weeks before the updated signature began being recognized again. Very annoying, but I guess I had to go through it. No way to argue with the ""wisdom" of MSFT.

Comment: As a bonus, the first installer can automatically choose the appropriate installation package (32/64bit, for example).

Comment: Yeah, I hear you brother.

Comment: I see no alternative to this solution, unless you go with an EV certificate. Otherwise you'll have the same problem again once your ceetificate exoires, loosing precious time waiting for "reputation"..

Comment: I tried to get an EV cert, but they didn't issue it to me as a sole proprietor (with a company.) Do you have any experience with EV certs yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It is by design of MS for every renewal you will have to build trust only then the smart screen filter will be removed for your certificate. If you need immediate reputation you need to purchase EV CS. I know it is too costly for EV CS but we have no other choice. Even microsoft don't answer this question. Either bare the cost or live with it wait for the reputation to build.

Comment: Well, saying "just purchase an EV cert" is not a fair answer. I tried and I they won't sell it to a freelance developer that is not associated with a business. Am I missing something about those EV certs?

Comment: For getting EV certs from CA you need to have registered business.. either get register as sole proprietor or a Pvt limited to obtain EV. It is a rule from CAB forum..