# OV certificate: How many downloads you need in order to get rid of the smart screen?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, code-signing

If I sign my application with an OV certificate, how many downloads I need until reputation builds up and the smart screen goes away?
Of course there are few possible ramifications here:

1. The OV certificate is brand new
2. The OV certificate expired and the renewed
3. The signed application is a new release (first time ever on Internet)
4. The signed application is an updated (had reputation before).

[Some](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222140/transferring-microsoft-smartscreen-reputation-to-renewed-certificate) people say that 10 downloads are enough, other say that you need tens of thousands of downloads.
Some people say that submitting the application to Microsoft will help, other say it won't.
There is anyone that actually undergone the process and can share some real data/statistics?

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23392404

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139347/smart-screen-filter-still-complains-despite-i-signed-the-executable-why

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't metered exactly, but it took me at least 5000 downloads in order to have my application past the "smart" screen.
That was the first time I signed my app.
My (blind) guess is that when one releases the same app second time, it might need fewer downloads.