# Is there a way to pass Smartscreen filter when creating an application with installshield limited?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, installshield, digital-certificate

I have created an application that I want to run as a desktop version on windows 8. I created the installer with installshield limited in visual studio. Now When I try to run the exe on windows 8, I get the smartscreen filter error. I did some research on it, and went through the following links:

1. [Digitally Signing Install Shield installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188064/digitally-signing-install-shield-installer)
2. [Microsoft SmartScreen & Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-amp-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates.aspx)

Now I am not sure whether to buy the standard code signing certificate or the one with extended validation. Comparison can be found [here](http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-code-signing-compared.htm).
Will buying standard certificate ensure that I pass the smartscreen filter the first time that installer is run on windows 8?
If someone can tell me any cheaper options to pass the filter, that will be great help.
TIA.

Answer (score 2):

The EV certificate will make sure that your users won't get shown the screen if you only have a couple download/installs. If more people install you application with a standard cert it will eventually not be shown to users aswell.