# How to publish Windows Forms apps on the Internet for Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, publish

I have uploaded my exe file to my server. But when user tries to download and run my app, he sees this message: "Windows SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk." Of course he can click "More info" and choose "Run anyway". But how to avoid it? Do I need some special certificate? How can I get it?

**What is the best way to publish Windows Forms apps on the Internet?**

I tried ClickOnce, made setup file using InnoSetup. Nothing works, SmartScreen still shows up.

By the way, I'm Windows Phone developer, my apps have more than 3,000,000 downloads. Can use this fact somehow to become a trusted publisher?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go for ClickOnce. And, yes, you need to sign your ClickOnce application with a certificate to be 'trusted' by Windows. You need a certificate with [Authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537359(v=vs.85).aspx) to be precise.

See the related [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172240.aspx) on this. Make sure your certificate comes from a CA that is trusted without the need for additional certificates to be installed.