# UWP authenticode signed appxbundle shows unknown publisher with smartscreen

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, signing, appx

I have a signed `appxbundle` generated by Visual Studio and signed with a Comodo authenticode sha256 certificate. The bundle shows a digital signature tab when opening the properties.

Now when I download the file on another PC, the `smartscreen` filter kicks in and says the `appxbundle` has an unknown publisher.

I researched this issue but it seems there are only solutions for clickonce deployments.

#### Update

I have also performed the solutions mentioned [here](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/). In short: using post build or pre-publish signing to sign the `.exe` files generated in the obj folder. Both these solutions do not solve the problem.

#### Update

Included certificate screenshot to show that certificate is valid:

[image]

My question: What do I need to do extra to make the `appxbundle` appear with the correct publisher?

#### Update

I checked with Comodo and rechecked the certificate chain. The application sideloads properly now but the Smartscreen still does not recognize the publisher.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application

Comment: This seems to be for hardware driver development.. When I go to the sysdev website, it asks for a verisign v3 certificate. This seems to be for system developers.... I just want to sideload an app

Comment: You probably checked, but is the certificate that you used to sign the app with, trusted on the other PC? Is the CA that issued that cert, trusted? You can check easily by opening the .cer file on the client PC and verify that the CertificationPath is all green

Comment: Hi Alex, all the certification paths are okay. I posted a screenshot in the question

Comment: I assume that screenshot is from the Target PC, not your development machine.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: I have seen this before, and it was caused by trusted root certificates not been updated on the target PC. Somehow related: http://serverfault.com/questions/752146/why-are-many-admins-using-turn-off-automatic-root-certificates-update-policy

Comment: I checked the list of Trusted Certificate Root Authorities and the Comodo Authority shows up in the list. Also, the automatic updating in the group policy is set to 'not set' which seems to be the normal setting.

Comment: It seems the problem is not completely solved yet: smartscreen does still not recognize the publisher properly. Could it be because the signature made by visual studio does not have a timestamp property?

Comment: which tool are you using to sign your package?

Comment: Vs2017 is used for signing

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the certificate by `mmc.exe`.

1. Run `mmc.exe`.
2. Click `File` From Menu and Click on `Add/Remove Snap-in...`.
3. Choose Certificates and Click on `Add >`.
4. Select `Computer Account` and then Choose `Local Computer` and click on `Finish`.
5. and then, Click on `OK`.
6. Navigate to `Certificates (Local Computer` then `Trusted Root Certificates` then `Certificates`.
7. Right-click on Item's Parent and select `All Tasks` and then `Import...` and then browse your certificate `*.cer` extension.
8. Save this console as `{Your_Name}.msc` and run uwp and check Trusted App if you completed the step then delete the `{Your_Name}.msc`.