# The signed MSI-package isn't liked by Windows

Tags: windows, windows-installer, code-signing, signtool, dsa

I have prepared my MSI package using the Advanced Installer and then signed it using the `SignTool`:

```
signtool sign /debug /f "cert.pfx" /fd SHA256
/p "<pass>" /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode "<file.msi>"
```

But, when other user is downloading the signed MSI via web-browser and to install it, the next message occurs:

[image]

My MSI has the next attributes:

- digital signature, which was generated with paid/commercial
  certificate (Comodo)
- timestamp
- there was used SHA-256 instead of SHA-1, because the last one is insecure in latest Windows

So, the **main question** is the next:

*Why doesn't Windows recognize my signed MSI as well-known, if I have signed it with the commercial code-signing certificate?*

PS

If you're interested in, which the version of Windows is used, then answer is `the latest Windows 10`.
About last one option from list, there is an interesting [link](http://support.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/215805-the-truth-about-sha1-sha-256-and-code-signing-certificates-), I shall quote some text from it:

> Effective January 1, 2016, Windows (version 7 and higher) and Windows
>   Server will no longer trust new code that is signed with a SHA-1 code
>   signing certificate for Mark-of-the-Web related scenarios (e.g. files
>   containing a digital signature) and that has been time-stamped with a
>   value greater than January 1, 2016. This cut-off date applies to the
>   code-signing certificate itself.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I do not see one being asked here.

Comment: @CodyGray the main question, what's wrong? Why Windows doesn't accept the signed MSI? Have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartScreen Protection can show the above message when you try to run a newly released program or an application that has not yet established a reputation.

Reputation is established by SmartScreen® service intelligence algorithms based on how an application is used by Windows and Internet Explorer users.

For details, check the passing the smart screen on [Win8 when install a signed application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application) thread that debates this subject.