# Prevent SmartScreen to pop up on my Windows Software installation

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am on windows 10.

I am using Microsoft extension called "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects" to make Installation wizard to pack my WinForms project with vs2015.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9/view/Reviews/3

The extension generates two files. For example: 
**setup.exe** and **yourSoftwareName.msi**

I use "WinZip Self Extractor" to pack everything to one EXE.

Anyhow, either type of installation (msi or exe) i always get the following screen:
[image]

I have read that i will need to purchase and setup "EV Code Signing Certificate" which cost a few hundreds dollars, depends on period of usage.

Is there a way besides massing with certifications to prevent this screen to popup?

Comment: `msi` files are already compressed and don't even need an `exe` to run, that's just a bootstrapper in case the latest installer version is missing. The `msi` file itself is enough. As for code signing certificates - who are you again? Why should the *end user* that activated SmartScreen trust that your application called IamNotReallyMalwarePosingAsWinforsm really comes from you?

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply. Regarding msi and exe thing. In my case it also check for framework 4.0 which might be missing in Windows XP.  Regarding certificate, you suggest EV Code signing certificate is a must?

Comment: There is no supported Windows version called XP or .NET version called 4.0. This isn't a joke - XP doesn't support TLS1.1 which is the minimum requirement nowadays, with many sites requiring TLS 1.2. You won't be able to connect to any service that requires HTTPS. Not sure if you can use certificates either. The minimum .NET version is 4.5.2

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback. You are saying that i might need to compile my project with framework 4.5.2 for setting up the certificate ? I understand this needs to be verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is: No there is no way.

See this documentation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/

You have only few options:

- buy a certificate from a trusted authority (digicert, symantec, ...) and
  sign your installation using it
- distribute your software via Windows Store
- turn off the smart screen filter on your PC

See this discussion for more info
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-applicatio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application)