# My game would not open because windows does not recognize it

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a game using **Unity3d** and I would like to have it open for downloading while I'm making it, so that if there are mistakes or bugs i don't notice, it'll be caught earlier. Before releasing the first playable version, I added an installer.

So, i put it up on **Gamejolt** (*it's like a free version of steam*), and I tested it by downloading it. When i tried to open the file, a screen pops out saying, **"Windows protected your computer"** and it keeps popping out every time. Is it okay to put a "more details" but i guess it will scare people away from downloading it because of the **"This app might put your computer at risk"** warning.

Is there a way to get Windows to recognize the app so that the warning message will not pop out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the smart screen on Win8 when install a signed application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application)

Comment: Quick answer - you need to get your code signed with a commercial certificate.